# Jupyter Notebook 404s when using Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Sorry but a bit of a beginner question here. I downloaded Anaconda library that comes with Jupyter Notebook along with a few other programs to hopefully learn Python. Every time I try to open Jupyter Notebook though, the webpage it directs me here `localhost:8888/tree` and gives me the following error:

> 404: Not Found error webpage.

**Edit**: After using the terminal to install pip, I got the following error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_u
nsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Y510P\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-0tanc911-uninstall\\users\\y510p\\documents\\anaconda\\lib\\site-pa
ckages\\zmq\\backend\\cython\\constants.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py",
 line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install
.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
 line 795, in install
    requirement.commit_uninstall()
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.
py", line 767, in commit_uninstall
    self.uninstalled.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstal
l.py", line 142, in commit
    rmtree(self.save_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying
.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying
.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying
.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, i
n reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying
.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.p
y", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_u
nsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_u
nsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_u
nsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  [Previous line repeated 5 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_u
nsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Y510P\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.p
y", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Y510P\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-0tanc911-uninstall\\users\\y510p\\documents\\anaconda\\lib\\site-pa
ckages\\zmq\\backend\\cython\\constants.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
```

Comment: Post URL for conformation purpose. Any errors..check error-logs too and post core if its there.

Comment: TBH.. its not completely clear if you did a Anaconda DL and got Jupyter alongside with it? Please elaborate on that in your question. Post also version numbers of Jupyter and conda.

Comment: Hey sorry about that. Yes, I got it with anaconda. I just tried going onto Jupyter's website itself (https://try.jupyter.org/) and it works fine with that, but launching it from Anaconda itself brings me to http://localhost:8891/tree causes the error. The product is the latest version, but how can I see which version it exactly is?

Also I get this as a error:

Comment: try in the command-line console `pip <packagename> --version`

Comment: can also be done by `pip search <packagename >` but thats a scroller result ;-) Read: `pip` or `conda`. They are both able to get you packages installed

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" Perhaps the file is hidden?

Comment: It looks like it is using port 8891, not 8888.

Comment: try `conda --version`. This should give the version-number of conda installed.

Comment: conda 4.4.8 and jupyter is 4.3.0 Also the port went to 91 as opposed to 88 after opening it a few times.

Comment: if my help was useful.. I bet the silence in comments tells its success story. Then check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about selecting the best answer and the consequence of doing so ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message gives:

> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time, to login with a token:
>       http://localhost:8891/?token=dcf34cac4a27f8b92397fcec424b228b308a4588f0473fd6

So try that first in your browser and see if the error persist.

Comment: I tried that, and still it just brings me to a 404 error.

Comment: I'm running jupyter notebook 5.3.1. Try at command-line `conda install notebook`. You should then get 5.3.1 as well. For pip: `pip install pip-upgrader` and then followed by `pip install --upgrade notebook `

Comment: So updating Conda and installing pip worked like a charm, but when I tried to update pip it gave me a new error message. See update in the main comment.

Comment: You have to roll back...because the other edit should remain in the question...otherwise all the comments can't be followed. And this what you added a minute ago should be marked as edit2.

Comment: try `pip -V` to see if pip works. You should get something like 9.0.1 or so. No upgrade needed then. Hence, install `pip-upgrader`.. its your little buddy when it comes to installing uupgraes from other packages that are not found by conda. Conda has update methods itself incontrast to pip.

Comment: the edit2 error is a build error. No worries atm. if `pip -V` works.. you're fine. The reason why you get this error is because there is a pip version installed... pip refuses to install twice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

what is the web page you're going to . If you're using windows . Go to cmd prompt . type `jupyter notebook` . If you're in mac os x . go to terminal and type `jupyter notebook`. LMK if it doesnt work .Also this is the link once you trigger jupyter notebook. :

http://localhost:8888/tree

LMK Know